# jquery & wordpress hide element when browser is a certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to execute a function which does this

1. Detects the screen size
2. Gets width of a certain DIV ".project-images" (sometimes this div will be 400px, other times it will be 1800px, 600px, etc. etc.)
3. If the DIV is smaller than the browser, hide another div ".controls"

I would this all done responsively too. I looked at other scripts on this website and managed to get this, but it's not working at all.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var $window = $(window);
    var $projectWidth = $('.project-images').width();

    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize > projectWidth) {
            $('.controls').hide();
        }
    }

    checkWidth();   
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div class="frame" id="centered" style="overflow: hidden;">
<ul class="clearfix project-images">
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
<li>List Item</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="controls center">
<button class="btn prev"></button>
<button class="btn next"></button>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You have a typo with `$projectWidth` and `projectWidth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo. Inside `if` you are refering to the wrong name variable.

You have declare `$projectWidth` and you are comparing `projectWidth`

Try this.

```
var $window = $(window);
    var $projectWidth = $('.project-images').width();

    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize > $projectWidth) {// Here you had the typo
            $('.controls').hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I feel so stupid. I'm new to jquery, so thank you.